# How to prevent my external API call from being called by anyone but me (my site)

Tags: ajax, security, front-end

My site sends different data to an external API under different circumstances. Luckily, most of it happens on form submissions, but there are a few instances where I need to make an API call from the client-side when a custom event fires.

```
$(document).on('someCustomEvent', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      uid: $('#user-wrap').data('uid'),
      action: 'add_user_by_uid',
      security: addUserVars.nonce   // addUserVars{} comes from wp_localize_script()
    }
  });
});
```

Then in functions.php I have:

```
function add_user_by_uid() {
  check_ajax_referer('add_user_nonce', 'security');

  $basic_auth = 'Basic ' . base64_encode( PUBLIC_KEY . ':' . PRIVATE_KEY );
  $headers = array( 
    'Authorization' => $basic_auth,
    'Content-type' => 'application/json'
  );

  return = wp_remote_post( 'https://api.example.com/add/', array(
    'headers' => $headers,
    'body' => json_encode(array('uid' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['uid']))
    )
  );
  die();
}
```

How can I prevent someone from creating their own POST request and executing this API call from their own site (obviously at times other than when `someCustomEvent` fires)?

I've always felt like using a nonce protected against this, but I've never really given it that much thought since most of my experience using AJAX in WP has **not** been with updating users and other critical info with a 3rd party API like this is.... Anyway, it sounds like this measure isn't terribly hard to get around. Is there a mitigation that is more appropriate for a scenario like this?

Comment: ***You can't***. you can only mitigate this without forcing a user to be logged in, and even then a user can just acquire a cookie or automate login. Although even with this, passing the `uid` directly to the remote API does not seem safe, especially with no sanitising

Comment: This was just a watered down version of the actual code to illustrate my issue. So there's no check (that can't be spoofed) I can do in `add_user_by_uid()` to make sure the POST is coming from my site or anything like that?

Comment: HTTP is stateless, if they have a valid cookie and know the details for basic auth, they can make the request. You can check the referrer but referrers can be spoofed. You can add a nonce, but if the server has access to the site they can just read the nonce. The server could use tools such as Cypress or Behat to manually click through your sites user interface in a headless browser. If you're asking for a cast iron canonical answer as your Q reads literally, then that is not possible. Otherwise you're going to have to refine the Q to refer to a specific mitigation

Comment: Question/code updated.